# Mapping a single response object with SwiftUI and MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I have a simple user profile model which is returned as a single node from a JSON API.

**(Model) UserProfile.swift**

```
struct UserProfile: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
    var profile: String
    var image: String?
    var status: String
    var timezone: String
}
```

**(Service) UserProfileService.swift**

```
class UserProfileService {    
    func getProfile(completion: @escaping(UserProfile?) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://myapi.com/profile") else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let profile = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserProfile.self, from: data)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(profile)
                }
            } catch {
                print("ERROR: ", error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**(View Model) UserProfileViewModel.swift**

```
class UserProfileRequestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var profile = UserProfile.self
    
    init() {
        fetchProfile()
    }
    
    func fetchProfile() {
        UserProfileService().getProfile { profile in
            if let profile = profile {
                self.profile = UserProfileViewModel.init(profile: profile)
            }
        }
    }
}

class UserProfileViewModel {
    var profile: UserProfile
    
    init(profile: UserProfile) {
        self.profile = profile
    }
    
    var id: Int {
        return self.profile.id
    }
}
```

Could someone please tell what I need to put instead `self.profile = UserProfileViewModel.init(profile: profile)` above as that results in the error "*Cannot assign value of type 'UserProfileViewModel' to type 'UserProfile.Type'"*?

If I have a loop of data, then there is no issue looping over this like below but how do I handle a single node?

```
if let videos = videos {
    self.videos = videos.map(VideoViewModel.init)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your UserProfileService().getProfile already return UserProfile type so you maybe need to

```
UserProfileService().getProfile { profile in
   if let profile = profile {
      self.profile = profile
   }
}
```

and

```
@Published var profile : UserProfile?
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I needed.
Although I don't understand the line "if let profile = profile { ... }?
Is that just checking there isn't an empty response?

Comment: Yes, it's. UserProfileService can return nil "completion(nil)" by "if let profile" we checking that. Also you need to return completion(nil) in your catch section (for case if you will have error in jsondecode)

Answer (score 0):

Working version with the correct View Model, so adding this for others that might have the same issues!

(View Model) UserProfileViewModel.swift

```
class UserProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var profile: UserProfile?
    
    init() {
        fetchProfile()
    }
    
    func fetchProfile() {
        UserProfileService().getProfile { profile in
              self.profile = profile
           
        }
    }
    
    var name: String {
        return self.profile?.name ?? "Name"
    }
}
```